# scrlttr2, crop and headheight

Tags: crop, scrlttr2, scrlayer-scrpage

I write a letter with `scrlttr2` and try to colorize the background of the header.

For some reason, I need some crop marks. So I maximize my letter from DIN-A4 to DIN-A3 with the package `crop`. But now, the colorized header background is too large.

I think the problem is the definition of the layer. I realized that with `scrlayer-scrpage`. I mean, I just copy+pasted it from an example I found somewhere at the Internet without understanding what really happened there ...

I hope someone can solve my problem :)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrlttr2}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareLayer[{%
    background,%
    align=lt,%
    area={0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\dimexpr\voffset+1in+\topmargin+\headheight\relax},
    contents={\color{green}\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}
}]{scrheadings.head.background}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{scrheadings.head.background}

\setkomavar{subject}{MWE}
\usepackage[cam,a3,center]{crop}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{adress 1\\
   adress 2\\
   adress 3\\
   adress 4\\
   adress 5}
\opening{Hi,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{kindly regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: letter (original A4)]

[image: letter with activated crop-option; header background is too height]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! The culprit seems to be `\voffset` which is obviously redefined by the `crop` package when the additional space is added above the actual page frame. I think, you can safely delete it, since in your original set up it has 0pt. (You can check this by putting `\the\voffset` somewhere on your page and load or unload the `crop` package.)

You may want to add some bleed of 3mm to the right, left and upper edge of the green block. So, you should be fine with the following:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrlttr2}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareLayer[{%
    background,%
    align=lt,%
    area={-3mm}{-3mm}{\paperwidth+6mm}{\dimexpr(1in+\topmargin+\headheight+3mm)\relax},
    contents={\color{green}\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}
}]{scrheadings.head.background}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{scrheadings.head.background}

\setkomavar{subject}{MWE}
\usepackage[cam,a3,center]{crop}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{adress 1\\
   adress 2\\
   adress 3\\
   adress 4\\
   adress 5}
\opening{Hi,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{kindly regards}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you very much :) Your explanations were very helpful.